# Json Object always return undefined from rest Api

Tags: javascript, cordova, android-studio, knockout.js

my question is about json object conversion. i am invoking rest api from knockout js in console its returning accurate data but when i want to select any object value then it always return undefined here is the code which i am using to extract value from json object.

```
}).then(function(response) {
   var headerObject1 = JSON.stringify(response.headers);
   var headerObject=JSON.parse(headerObject1);
   var wwwContext = headerObject['WWW-Authenticate'];
   alert(wwwContext);
   var mainTokens = wwwContext.split(',');
   var subTokens = mainTokens[1].split('=');
```

i am using cordova in android studio when i alert on wwwContext then it always showing undefined.[Alert Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asvGH.png)
any one guide me what is the issue in my code.

Comment: `var headerObject1 = JSON.stringify(response.headers);` that looks wrong

Comment: why mean i dont need to stringify this object direct parse it?

Comment: @JaromandaX when i remove stringify then it gives syntax error

Comment: @AmmarMuhiUdDin can you post working code snippet using JSFIDDLE or Plunker etc?

Comment: Are you using fetch API

Comment: @JaromandaX i am using cordovafetch.